# Low ssh performance

Tags: performance, openssh

i have low transmission speed over ssh tunnel. I test the ciphers with this command:

```
for i in `ssh -Q cipher`; do dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 2> /dev/null   | ssh -c $i server "(time -p cat) > /dev/null" 2>&1   | grep real | awk '{print "'$i': "100 / $2" MB/s" }'; done
```

and results are there.

```
aes128-ctr: 14.7275 MB/s
aes192-ctr: 15.949 MB/s
aes256-ctr: 15.2905 MB/s
aes128-gcm@openssh.com: 6.55308 MB/s
aes256-gcm@openssh.com: 13.9276 MB/s
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com: 10.582 MB/s
```

The server is a Ryzen 3600 and the SO is ubuntu 22.04, I revised the config, tried different options but the speed not change. What can I do?

Comment: What CPU does the _client_ have? What is the unencrypted (non-SSH) network throughput measured with `iperf3`?

Comment: What is the performance if you set the cipher to `none`?

Comment: Is this perhaps a high-latency link?